単語ベクトルの生成方法について
長文かつ文がまとまっておらず読みにくかったらすみません。プログラミング、自然言語処理ともに初学者のため、間違った用語の使い方などあると思います。
やりたいこと:
まず基本的な語彙のみで作った元となる単語ベクトルを作っておいて、難しい単語をその単語ベクトルを使って一つずつ予測する手法と四択の中から正解を当てる手法で学習させてどちらが最終的に精度のいい単語ベクトルになるかを調べたいです。この二つの手法で完成させるのが目標ですが、これができたらさらにもう一つ四択に「この中には正解はない」という選択肢を追加して予測する手法のものも作りたいです。
できているところ:
予測をするところまではできています。パラメータを更新するところもできていると思います。
困っていること:
そもそも基本的な語彙のみで作られた学習前のモデルに予測したい言葉は含まれていないので計算ができないです。ここまで長々と書いてしまいましたがここが解決すればあとは何とかなる気がしています。試したコードでは、予測したい単語のベクトルをモデル内の学習済みモデルから取得しているので、自分のやりたいこととは違うというのが問題です。
分からない個所や説明が不明瞭な点があれば聞いてください。お願いします。
予測までのコード:
#ver1.10
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_md # Download the required spaCy model

#実行時間短縮
import spacy
import numpy as np
import random
import re  # 正規表現ライブラリ
import concurrent.futures  # 並列処理のためのライブラリ

import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown, names
from nltk import pos_tag

# NLTKのデータセットをダウンロード
nltk.download('brown')
nltk.download('names')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

# Spacyのモデルをロード
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

# Spacyの最大テキスト長を増やす
nlp.max_length = 2000000

# Brownコーパスの単語リストを取得（すべて小文字に変換し、原型に統一）
brown_words = [word.lower() for word in brown.words()]

# テキストをチャンクに分割して処理
def lemmatize_chunk(chunk):
    doc = nlp(" ".join(chunk))
    return [token.lemma_ for token in doc]

def lemmatize_words(words, chunk_size=100000):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        chunks = [words[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(words), chunk_size)]
        results = executor.map(lemmatize_chunk, chunks)
    lemmas = []
    for result in results:
        lemmas.extend(result)
    return lemmas

brown_lemmas = lemmatize_words(brown_words)

# 単語頻度リストを取得（原型に基づいて計算）
word_freq = nltk.FreqDist(brown_lemmas)

# 名前のリストを取得（すべて小文字に変換）
name_list = [name.lower() for name in names.words()]

# 名前、前置詞、冠詞、記号、短縮形、数字を除外
def is_valid_word(word, pos):
    return (word.lower() not in name_list and
            pos not in ('IN', 'DT', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'WP', 'WP$', 'NM') and
            not all(char in '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~' for char in word) and
            "'" not in word and
            not bool(re.search(r'\d', word))) and len(word) > 2

# 頻度上位の単語を取得し、POSタグを付ける 基本語彙
basic_vocab = [word for word, freq in word_freq.most_common(1000)]
tagged_basic_vocab = pos_tag(basic_vocab)

# フィルタリング
filtered_basic_vocab = [word for word, pos in tagged_basic_vocab if is_valid_word(word, pos)]

# ベクトルの生成
basic_vectors = {word: nlp(word).vector for word in filtered_basic_vocab}

# 上位1000〜2000の単語を取得し、POSタグを付ける 予測したい言葉
difficult_vocab = [word for word, freq in word_freq.most_common()[1000:2000]]
tagged_difficult_vocab = pos_tag(difficult_vocab)

filtered_difficult_vocab = [word for word, pos in tagged_difficult_vocab if is_valid_word(word, pos)]

# ベクトルの生成
difficult_vectors = {word: nlp(word).vector for word in filtered_difficult_vocab}

# 1~4000まで単語を取得し、POSタグを付ける 選択肢用
choices_vocab = [word for word, freq in word_freq.most_common()[1000:4000]]
tagged_choices_vocab = pos_tag(choices_vocab)

filtered_choices_vocab = [word for word, pos in tagged_choices_vocab if is_valid_word(word, pos)]

# 単語ベクトルを使って類似度を計算
def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
    return np.dot(vec1, vec2) / (np.linalg.norm(vec1) * np.linalg.norm(vec2))

# 一対一で予測する関数
def one_to_one_prediction(difficult_word):
    difficult_vector = nlp(difficult_word).vector
    similarities = {word: cosine_similarity(difficult_vector, vector) for word, vector in basic_vectors.items()}
    predicted_word = max(similarities, key=similarities.get)
    return predicted_word

# 四択で予測する関数
def multiple_choice_prediction(difficult_word):
    choices = random.sample(filtered_choices_vocab, 3)
    correct_choice = difficult_word  # ここがdifficult_word
    choices.append(correct_choice)  # 正しい選択肢を追加
    random.shuffle(choices)

    difficult_vector = nlp(difficult_word).vector
    similarities = {choice: cosine_similarity(difficult_vector, nlp(choice).vector) for choice in choices}
    predicted_word = max(similarities, key=similarities.get)
    return predicted_word, correct_choice, choices

# 四択プラス「この中にはない」で予測する関数
def multiple_choice_with_none_prediction(difficult_word):
    correct_choice = difficult_word
    none_choice = "None of the above"
    choices = random.sample(filtered_choices_vocab, 3)
    choices.append(none_choice)

    # 1/2の確率で "None of the above" を追加するか選択肢の一部として含める
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        choices = random.sample(filtered_choices_vocab, 3)
        choices.append(none_choice)
        choices.append(correct_choice)
        correct_is_in_choices = True
    else:
        choices = random.sample(filtered_choices_vocab, 4)
        choices.append(none_choice)
        correct_is_in_choices = False

    random.shuffle(choices)

    difficult_vector = nlp(difficult_word).vector
    similarities = {choice: cosine_similarity(difficult_vector, nlp(choice).vector) for choice in choices if choice != none_choice}
    predicted_word = max(similarities, key=similarities.get)

    if not correct_is_in_choices or predicted_word not in choices:
        predicted_word = none_choice

    return predicted_word, correct_choice, choices

# テスト
def run_tests(num_tests=10):
    for _ in range(num_tests):
        difficult_word = random.choice(filtered_difficult_vocab)
        test_one_to_one_prediction(difficult_word)
        test_multiple_choice_prediction(difficult_word)
        test_multiple_choice_with_none_prediction(difficult_word)

# 一対一で予測
def test_one_to_one_prediction(difficult_word):
    print("One-to-One Prediction:")
    predicted = one_to_one_prediction(difficult_word)
    print(f"Predicted: {predicted}, Correct: {difficult_word}")

# 四択で予測
def test_multiple_choice_prediction(difficult_word):
    print("\nMultiple Choice Prediction:")
    predicted, correct, choices = multiple_choice_prediction(difficult_word)
    print(f"Predicted: {predicted}, Correct: {correct}, Choices: {choices}")

# 四択プラス「この中にはない」で予測
def test_multiple_choice_with_none_prediction(difficult_word):
    print("\nMultiple Choice with None Prediction:")
    predicted, correct, choices = multiple_choice_with_none_prediction(difficult_word)
    print(f"Predicted: {predicted}, Correct: {correct}, Choices: {choices}")
    if correct == "None of the above" and predicted != correct:
        print(f"Problem word: {difficult_word}")

# テスト実行
run_tests()


試したコード:
#Ver1.301 教師アリ学習に変更 sub wordも考慮してやる単語ベクトルに変更　one to one

!pip install spacy
!pip install fasttext
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

import spacy
import nltk
import fasttext

# NLTKのデータセットをダウンロード
nltk.download('brown')
nltk.download('names')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

# Spacyのモデルをロード
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
nlp.max_length = 2000000

# FastTextモデルをダウンロード
!wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-wiki/wiki.en.zip
!unzip wiki.en.zip

# FastTextモデルをロード
ft_model = fasttext.load_model('wiki.en.bin')

# モデルとデータの保存
import pickle
with open('nlp_model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(nlp, f)
with open('ft_model.bin', 'wb') as f:
    ft_model.save_model('ft_model.bin')

import spacy
import numpy as np
import fasttext
import random
import re
import concurrent.futures
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown, names
from nltk import pos_tag
import pickle
import copy

# 初期学習率のリスト
learning_rates = [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]

# モデルの読み込み
with open('nlp_model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    nlp = pickle.load(f)
ft_model = fasttext.load_model('ft_model.bin')

# Brownコーパスの単語リストを取得（すべて小文字に変換）
brown_words = [word.lower() for word in brown.words()]

# テキストをチャンクに分割して処理
def lemmatize_chunk(chunk):
    doc = nlp(" ".join(chunk))
    return [token.lemma_ for token in doc]

def lemmatize_words(words, chunk_size=100000):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        chunks = [words[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(words), chunk_size)]
        results = executor.map(lemmatize_chunk, chunks)
    lemmas = []
    for result in results:
        lemmas.extend(result)
    return lemmas

brown_lemmas = lemmatize_words(brown_words)

# 単語頻度リストを取得（原型に基づいて計算）
word_freq = nltk.FreqDist(brown_lemmas)

# 名前のリストを取得（すべて小文字に変換）
name_list = [name.lower() for name in names.words()]

# 名前、前置詞、冠詞、記号、短縮形、数字を除外
def is_valid_word(word, pos):
    return (word.lower() not in name_list and
            pos not in ('IN', 'DT', 'PRP', 'PRP$', 'WP', 'WP$', 'NM') and
            not all(char in '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~' for char in word) and
            "'" not in word and
            not bool(re.search(r'\d', word))) and len(word) > 2

# 頻度上位の単語を取得し、POSタグを付ける 基本語彙
basic_vocab = [word for word, freq in word_freq.most_common(1000)]
tagged_basic_vocab = pos_tag(basic_vocab)

# フィルタリング
filtered_basic_vocab = [word for word, pos in tagged_basic_vocab if is_valid_word(word, pos)]

# ベクトルの生成（FastTextを使用）
basic_vectors = {word: ft_model.get_word_vector(word) for word in filtered_basic_vocab}

# 基本ベクトルの初期状態を保存
initial_basic_vectors = copy.deepcopy(basic_vectors)

# 上位1000〜2000の単語を取得し、POSタグを付ける 予測したい言葉
difficult_vocab = [word for word, freq in word_freq.most_common()[1000:2000]]
tagged_difficult_vocab = pos_tag(difficult_vocab)

filtered_difficult_vocab = [word for word, pos in tagged_difficult_vocab if is_valid_word(word, pos)]

# 1~4000まで単語を取得し、POSタグを付ける 選択肢用
choices_vocab = [word for word, freq in word_freq.most_common()[1000:4000]]
tagged_choices_vocab = pos_tag(choices_vocab)

filtered_choices_vocab = [word for word, pos in tagged_choices_vocab if is_valid_word(word, pos)]

# 単語ベクトルを使って類似度を計算
def cosine_similarity(vec1, vec2):
    return np.dot(vec1, vec2) / (np.linalg.norm(vec1) * np.linalg.norm(vec2))

# 一対一で予測する関数
def one_to_one_prediction(difficult_word, basic_vectors):
    difficult_word_vector = ft_model.get_word_vector(difficult_word)
    similarities = {word: cosine_similarity(difficult_word_vector, vector) for word, vector in basic_vectors.items()}
    predicted_word = max(similarities, key=similarities.get)
    return predicted_word

# 精度を計算する関数
def calculate_accuracy(difficult_vocab, basic_vectors, threshold=0.7):
    correct_predictions = 0
    for difficult_word in difficult_vocab:
        predicted = one_to_one_prediction(difficult_word, basic_vectors)
        predicted_vector = basic_vectors.get(predicted, np.zeros(300))  # ベクトルが存在しない場合はゼロベクトルを使用
        difficult_word_vector = ft_model.get_word_vector(difficult_word)
        similarity = cosine_similarity(predicted_vector, difficult_word_vector) 
        if similarity >= threshold:
            correct_predictions += 1
    accuracy = correct_predictions / len(difficult_vocab)
    return accuracy

# ベクトルの最適化（教師あり学習）
def optimize_basic_vectors_with_teacher(basic_vectors, filtered_difficult_vocab, learning_rate=0.1, epochs=100):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        total_loss = 0
        random.shuffle(filtered_difficult_vocab)  # データのランダム化
        for difficult_word in filtered_difficult_vocab:
            difficult_word_vector = ft_model.get_word_vector(difficult_word)

            # 一対一の予測を行う
            predicted_word = one_to_one_prediction(difficult_word, basic_vectors)
            predicted_vector = basic_vectors.get(predicted_word, np.zeros(300))  # ベクトルが存在しない場合はゼロベクトルを使用

            # 勾配計算
            grad = 2 * (predicted_vector - difficult_word_vector)

            # ベクトル更新
            if predicted_word in basic_vectors:
                basic_vectors[predicted_word] -= learning_rate * grad

            # 損失計算
            loss = np.linalg.norm(predicted_vector - difficult_word_vector) ** 2
            total_loss += loss

        #print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}, Loss: {total_loss}")

for i in range(len(learning_rates)):
    # 学習前の精度のリスト
    Initial_accurasy_list = []

    # 学習後の精度のリスト
    Final_accurasy_list = []

    learning_rate = learning_rates[i]

    for j in range(3):  # 3回繰り返す
        print(f"Learning Rate: {learning_rate} (Iteration {j + 1}/3)")

        # basic_vectorsを初期状態にリセット
        basic_vectors = copy.deepcopy(initial_basic_vectors)

        # 最適化前の精度を計算
        initial_accuracy = calculate_accuracy(filtered_difficult_vocab, basic_vectors)
        Initial_accurasy_list.append(initial_accuracy)
        print(f"Initial Accuracy: {initial_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

        # 最適化の実行（教師あり学習）
        optimize_basic_vectors_with_teacher(basic_vectors, filtered_difficult_vocab, learning_rate, epochs=100)

        # 最適化後の精度を計算
        final_accuracy = calculate_accuracy(filtered_difficult_vocab, basic_vectors)
        Final_accurasy_list.append(final_accuracy)
        print(f"Final Accuracy: {final_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

    avg_initial_accuracy = (sum(Initial_accurasy_list) / len(Initial_accurasy_list)) * 100
    avg_final_accuracy = (sum(Final_accurasy_list) / len(Final_accurasy_list)) * 100

    print(f"Average of Initial Accuracy: {avg_initial_accuracy:.2f}%")
    print(f"Average of Final Accuracy: {avg_final_accuracy:.2f}%")



調べている途中ですが、fasttextモデルではsub wordという細かい区切りに単語を分けて未知語に対応しているらしいのですが、その仕組みをこれにも応用できないか検討中です。ほかの解決策などもあればぜひ教えていただきたいです。
